# numpy: applying argsort to an array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

The [`argsort()`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.argsort.html#numpy.argsort) function returns a matrix of indices that can be used to index the original array so that the result would match the `sort()` result.

Is there a way to apply those indices? I have two arrays, one is the array used for obtaining the sort order, and another is some associated data.

I would like to compute `assoc_data[array1.argsort()]` but that doesn't seem to work.

Here's an example:

```
z=array([1,2,3,4,5,6,7])
z2=array([z,z*z-7])
i=z2.argsort()
```

---

```
z2=array([[ 1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7],
          [-6, -3,  2,  9, 18, 29, 42]])
i =array([[1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
          [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1]])
```

I would like to apply i to z2 (or another array with associated data) but I'm not sure how to do so.

Comment: Which axis do you want to sort along?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is probably overkill, but this will work in the nd case:

```
import numpy as np
axis = 0
index = list(np.ix_(*[np.arange(i) for i in z2.shape]))
index[axis] = z2.argsort(axis)
z2[index]

# Or if you only need the 3d case you can use np.ogrid.

axis = 0
index = np.ogrid[:z2.shape[0], :z2.shape[1], :z2.shape[2]]
index[axis] = z2.argsort(axis)
z2[index]
```

Comment: oddly enough I needed this again exactly a year later, and in searching for how to do it, I ran across the question I asked before.... I finally understand what this does. It doesn't look like overkill, btw.

Answer (score 5):

You're lucky I just got my masters degree in numpyology.

```
>>> def apply_argsort(a, axis=-1):
...     i = list(np.ogrid[[slice(x) for x in a.shape]])
...     i[axis] = a.argsort(axis)
...     return a[i]
... 
>>> a = np.array([[1,2,3,4,5,6,7],[-6,-3,2,9,18,29,42]])
>>> apply_argsort(a,0)
array([[-6, -3,  2,  4,  5,  6,  7],
       [ 1,  2,  3,  9, 18, 29, 42]])
```

For an explanation of what's going on, see my answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10921893/numpy-sorting-a-multidimensional-array-by-a-multidimensional-array/10922358#10922358).

Answer (score 3):

Use `np.take_along_axis`

```
np.take_along_axis(z2, i, axis=1)
Out[31]: 
array([[ 1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7],
       [-6, -3,  2,  9, 18, 29, 42]])
```

Comment: that's not the answer I am looking for, but it does look like `np.take_along.axis` can be used for this purpose, if called correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Aha, figured it out.

```
In [274]: z2[i,range(z2.shape[1])]
Out[274]:
array([[-6, -3,  2,  4,  5,  6,  7],
       [ 1,  2,  3,  9, 18, 29, 42]])
```

Comment: Plus you didn't say what i was ;)

Comment: Oops sorry, got confused by the fact there are two i's in your question and I was looking at the "wrong" one (the first one, that doesn't work when plugged in your answer)