# python numpy array indexed by a whole array

Tags: python, numpy

```
t_index = np.argsort(adj, axis = 0)[:,::-1]  # 54 x 54 shape   
t = np.sort(adj, axis= 0)[:,::-1] # 54 x 54
t[5:,] = 0
adj = t[t_index] # 54 x 54 x 54
```

Instead of returning a 54 x 54 shape, it is 54 x 54 x 54. How can I get the same shape? Why is it three-dimensional?

Comment: Just a minor note, in python multidimensional arrays are indexed `t[i, j]` instead of `t[i][j]`.

Comment: Can you explain what you are trying to achieve? I think I see what you are trying to do, and there are much simpler approaches. You definitely shouldn't need to both `sort` and `argsort` an array no matter what you are trying to do. My guess is that what you want to do is: `t_index = np.argsort(adj, axis=0); mask = (t_index < adj.shape[0] - 5); adj[mask] = 0`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let me give you an example of who we use the `t[t_index]` syntax to help you understand how it works. I sometimes use integer arrays to represent images using a color pallet. Each of 256 colors, rgb values, are stored in a pallet array that has shape (256, 3). The image is stored as an array of (1000, 1000) integers between 0 and 255, or indices into the pallet array. If I want to create an rgb image, for example for display purpose i do `rgbimage = pallet[image]` to create an rgb image which is (1000, 1000, 3).

update:
I see that you've updated your question in include argsort, maybe you're trying to do something similar tho [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11253495/numpy-applying-argsort-to-an-array/11253931#11253931). For a 2d array, the short version looks like this:

```
s = np.random.random((54, 54))
t = np.random.random((54, 54))
axis = 0

t_index = s.argsort(axis)
idx = np.ogrid[:t.shape[0], :t.shape[1]]
idx[axis] = t_index
t_sort = t[idx]
```

I was looking for a good explanation of how this works, but I can't seem to find a good one. If anyone has a good reference for how `ogrid` works, or how broadcasting in numpy indexing works please leave a note in the comments. I'll write a short explanation which should help.
Lets say `t` is a 2d array and I want to pick out 2 elements from each column, I would do the following:

```
t = np.arange((12)).reshape(3, 4)
print t
# [[ 0,  1,  2,  3],
#  [ 4,  5,  6,  7],
#  [ 8,  9, 10, 11]]

print t[[0, 3], :]
# [[ 0  1  2  3]
#  [ 8  9 10 11]]
```

Now imagine I want different elements from each row, I might try:

```
row_index = [[0, 2],
             [0, 2],
             [1, 2],
             [0, 1]]
t[row_index]
# Which in python is the same as
t[row_index, :]
```

But that will not work. This behavior shouldn't be surprising because the `:` means every column. In the previous example we got every column for 0, and every column for 2. What we really want is:

```
row_index = [[0, 2],
             [0, 2],
             [1, 2],
             [0, 1]]
column_index = [[0, 0],
                [1, 1],
                [2, 2],
                [3, 3]]
t[row_index, column_index]
```

Numpy also lets us cheat and use the following because the values are just repeated:

```
column_index = [[0],
                [1],
                [2],
                [3]]
```

Read about [broadcasting](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html) to understand this better. I hope this explanation is helpful.