# Row-wise indexing in Numpy

Tags: python, numpy, indexing

I have two matrices, `A` and `B`:

```
A = array([[2., 13., 25., 1.], [ 18., 5., 1., 25.]])
B = array([[2, 1], [0, 3]])
```

I want to index each row of `A` with each row of `B`, producing the slice:

```
array([[25., 13.], [18., 25.]])
```

That is, I essentially want something like:

```
array([A[i,b] for i,b in enumerate(B)])
```

Is there a way to fancy-index this directly? The best I can do is this "flat-hack":

```
A.flat[B + arange(0,A.size,A.shape[1])[:,None]]
```

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10921893/numpy-sorting-a-multidimensional-array-by-a-multidimensional-array/10922358#10922358

Answer (score 13, accepted):

@Ophion's answer is great, and deserves the credit, but I wanted to add some explanation, and offer a more intuitive construction.

Instead of rotating `B` and then rotating the result back, it's better to just rotate the `arange`.  I think this gives the most intuitive solution, even if it takes more characters:

```
A[((0,),(1,)), B]
```

or equivalently

```
A[np.arange(2)[:, None], B]
```

This works because what's really going on here, is you're making an `i` array and a `j` array, each of which have the same shape as your desired result.

```
i = np.array([[0, 0],
              [1, 1]])
j = B
```

But you can use just

```
i = np.array([[0],
              [1]])
```

Because it will broadcast to match `B` (this is what `np.arange(2)[:,None]` gives).

Finally, to make it more general (not knowing `2` as the `arange` size), you could also generate `i` from `B` with

```
i = np.indices(B.shape)[0]
```

however you build `i` and `j`, you just call it like

```
>>> A[i, j]
array([[ 25.,  13.],
       [ 18.,  25.]])
```

Comment: This is the more thought out solution. I especially like it because `A.flat[np.ravel_multi_index((np.arange(2)[:,None],B),A.shape)]` makes more sense when shown this way.

Comment: There's also some great solution out there using `np.r_` but that really confuses me, and was designed for people used to `MATLAB` notation, which I'm not.

Comment: @askewchan, I solved the N dimensional version of this here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10921893/numpy-sorting-a-multidimensional-array-by-a-multidimensional-array/10922358#10922358

Answer (score 9):

Not pretty but:

```
A[np.arange(2),B.T].T
array([[ 25.,  13.],
       [ 18.,  25.]])
```

Comment: Aha, I didn't think to transpose B. That's much cleaner.