# Fancy indexing to replace the values of an N dimensional array?

Tags: python, numpy

I am currently working with a numpy array containing pixel color information of shape (width, height, 3).

I would like to be able to replace colors in the original array, with colors described in a new array and to do this WITHOUT loops if possible.

I have tried indexing it with fancy index's but was not quite sure how to index properly.

Optimally the function would like something like this:

```
>>>import numpy as np
>>>imgdat = np.random.randint(0, 255, size=(2, 2, 3))
>>>imgdat
   [[[138 149  41]
     [100 186 136]]

    [[181 202 169]
     [205 247 195]]]
>>>pixels = np.random.randint(0, imgdat.shape[0], size=(2, 2))
>>>pixels
   [[1,0]
    [0,1]]
>>>colors = np.random.randint(0, 255, size=(2, 3))
>>>colors
   [[ 16 229 138]
    [ 86  76 209]]
######apply the function#######
>>>filledimgdat = fillPixels(imgdat, pixels, colors) 
>>>filledimgdat
   [[[ 138 149  41]
     [ 86  76 209]]

    [[ 16 229 138]
     [205 247 195]]]
```

EDIT:

Because my originally description was a little unclear, what I am trying to do is replace specific colors in imgdat at specific index's. If anybody can think of a better way to format the datatypes or handle the info to simplify an operation like this, that would also be welcome.

Comment: `imgdat[0] = colors`?

Comment: Because I am only changing the colors with the index's described in pixels I don't think that would work.

Comment: Could you explain the expected output?

Comment: What I am doing is creating an array 'pixels' which describes the index's of the rows that should be replaced in 'imgdat' and then defining what those index's values are with 'colors'.  Expected output would be an array with imgdat's values (where the index matchs that in pixels) is replaced with the color in 'colors'. But if you can think of a better way to format the datatypes, shapes or operations it would be welcome as I am not super comfortable with numpy. Essentially I'm replacing specific 'color rows' of an array of shape (width, height, 3) where 3 is the RGB components of the color.

Comment: The second half of my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10921893/numpy-sorting-a-multidimensional-array-by-a-multidimensional-array/10922358#10922358 may help you to understand how fancy indexing works.

Comment: Thanks! That was actually super helpful.